# Can array_unique be used for multi dimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, array-unique

i just wanted to know whether array_unique be used for multi dimensional arrays

Comment: @Karl In php just like its tagged :)

Comment: @tomaszsobczak: If you look closely at the time, the PHP-tag was added after he asked that ;)

Comment: @elusive - my fault, sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://php.net/array_unique):

> Note that array_unique() is not intended to work on multi dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 1):

From php.net's [page on array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

> Note: Note that array_unique() is not
>   intended to work on multi dimensional
>   arrays

Answer (score 0):

array_unique() is not intended to work on multi dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

just go here http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php and read this "**Note: Note that array_unique() is not intended to work on multi dimensional arrays**"

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$array = array(
    array(
        'id'    => 123,
        'name'  => 'Some Product',
        'ean'   => '1234567890123'
    ),
    array(
        'id'    => 123,
        'name'  => 'Some Product',
        'ean'   => '4852950174938'
    ),
    array(
        'id'    => 123,
        'name'  => 'Some Product',
        'ean'   => '1234567890123'
    ),
);
$uniqueArray = array_unique($array);
var_dump($uniqueArray);
?>
```

Output

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(123)
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "Some Product"
    ["ean"]=>
    string(13) "1234567890123"
  }
}
```

Please see that `http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php`